# Navigating to a nested screen with react navigation but using a reset/replace action?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have an app with multiple stack navigators (nested). The [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) say that you navigate to a nested screen like:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', { screen: 'Settings' });
```

However, in my situation I don't want to allow the user to go back so I want to use a reset/replace action. How would you do that?

The documentation says how to do a reset to a route, but doesn't give info on how to specify the screen e.g.

```
navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{name: 'Root'}], //Where to put screen?
      });
```

**EDIT** Here is my setup
On the top level I have 3 screens in a stack:

```
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HiddenScreen"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HiddenScreen"
        component={HiddenScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="VideoConferenceIncoming"
        component={VideoConferenceIncoming}
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="CreateUser" component={CreateUser} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Now the CreateUser Screen has a stack inside it too:

```
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={initialRoute}
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Step1" component={CreateUserStep1} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Step2" component={CreateUserStep2} />
            <Stack.Screen name="UserRegistered" component={UserRegistered} />
            <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
            <Stack.Screen name="WaitingRoom" component={WaitingRoom} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
```

Let's say I am currently inside the VideoConferenceIncoming screen. I want to navigate to the CreateUser>Waiting Room screen. However, I do not want the allow the user to go back.

Currently I have this solution which is not quite right:

```
      navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{name: 'CreateUser'}],
      });
      navigation.navigate('CreateUser', {
        screen: 'WaitingRoom',
        params: {queuePosition: qPos, ticketNumber: ticketNumber},
      });
```

It's not right because the user from the WaitingRoom screen can still go back a step.

Comment: It would be helpful to add your router structure to the question since it cannot be understood what kind of navigators you are using, what level of nesting is present.

Comment: I have added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset) tells you how to do it. But can be a bit difficult to understand if you are new to react-navigation and how it works.

What it says is that you can now set the state of the nested navigator when using `reset`. So you can specify the specific screen you want to navigate to in the navigator state that you are setting.

So in your case, resetting would be like below.

```
navigation.dispatch(
 CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
        {
            name: 'CreateUser',
            state: {
                routes: [{name: 'WaitingRoom'}],
            },
        },
    ],
  }),
);
```